# How to solve "androidx.*...*.ConstraintLayout" is not allowed when converting activity_main.xml to data binding layout?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, android-constraintlayout

DataBinding configration in build.gradle is "enabled = true", but the compiler always show "Element androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout is not allowed here", when I just convert constraintlayout to data binding layout and do nothing else.

Basic information:
Android Studio 3.5.1; 
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203, built on September 26, 2019; 
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64; 
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o; 
Windows 10

If I use other layouts such as linearlayout, framelayout and so on, compiler will not go wrong. Kotlin can build successfully with this error (but app won't work as expected) while Java can not, I tried cleaning build, restarting AS and my PC for many times, but still the compiler show this error.
I wonder if it is a bug of AS 3.5, or I did anything wrong? Help me please and thanks in advance.

```
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app15"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        dataBinding{
            enabled = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Solved by using "dataBinding.enabled = true" statement instead of dataBinding{} block

Answer (score 0):

If you see compiler errors after you make changes, select **Build > Clean Project** followed by **Build > Rebuild**.

Doing this usually updates the generated files. Otherwise, select **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart** to do a more thorough cleanup.